# Call to a member function createCommand() on null

Tags: php, yii2

Когда пытаюсь делать так из модели:

```
$сonnection = Yii::$app->db;
$connection->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

выдает ошибку:

> Call to a member function createCommand() on null

Модель использует:

```
use Yii;
use yii\db\Command;
```

Что я забыл, где ошибка?

Пробовал еще так:

```
$db = new yii\db\Connection([
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);
$db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Точно такая же ошибка.

Comment: судя по ошибку `$сonnection` - `null`, а значит `null` вернул `Yii::$app->db`

Comment: @Grundy, пробовал подключить прямо в моделе     `$db = new yii\db\Connection([
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);`

такая же ошибка

Comment: @bemulima уверены что второй вариант точно не работает? Объект создается и сразу вызывается, он не может быть `null`.

Comment: @Onedev.Link, да, правда не работает, такое чувство, что для use еще что то надо подключить

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема, когда перешёл с php7 на php7.2 и забыл поставить модуль mysqli.